# Xcode: different 'Required background modes' for different build configs

Tags: ios, xcode

My goal is to have different background mode enabled for different configurations. I want to make my app does continues background location tracking in the debug build for testing purposes, so I need `Required background modes: location` when I use my debug config, but not when I use the release config.

I've tried using a user-defined setting in my target's build settings, and set the variable in the info.plist like this:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>${BACKGROUND_LOCATION}</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

`BACKGROUND_LOCATION = "location"` for release config, and `BACKGROUND_LOCATION = ""` for debug config.

It works locally but will fail App Store validation because the plist contains an invalid value `''`.

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to add or hide a row to an array using user-defined settings. Nay suggestions?

p.s. I know I can achieve my goal with two different info.plist, but that seems like a pain to maintain :(